# How to count items in listbox using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, counting

I am having an issue with counting items in a list. I would like the number of counted items to be displayed in the window I created. How to do this with
listbox.size() ?
`

> def count_tasks()
> listbox.index("end")
>
> button_count_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Count tasks",
> width=48, command=count_tasks)  button_count_tasks.pack()`

how to make it work? and how to show results in some box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the listbox to return you the index of the last element:

```
the_listbox.index("end")
```

The number that is returned corresponds to the number of items in the listbox.

If you want to show it in "some box", you just need to insert the box or configure it, depending on what you mean by "some box". If it's an existing label then it would be something like:

```
count = the_listbox.index("end")
the_label.configure(text=f"{count} items in listbox")
```

Comment: but how to connect it?

Comment: `button_count_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Count tasks", width=48, command=count_tasks)
button_count_tasks.pack()`

Comment: @Roberto: you didn't provide any code so I can't answer that. All you need is a reference to the listbox, how  you do that is up to you.

Comment: @Roberto: create a function, call the function from the button.

Comment: `def count_tasks the_listbox.index("end") button_count_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Count tasks", width=48, command=count_tasks) button_count_tasks.pack()` and how to show the final amount in some box?